# Showing only max value of case statement in group by statement in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

With a query I'd like to check for all the loans in our database, whether they main credit taker has an e-mail address filled out or not.

The problem I am encountering is that the Address table stores various types of addresses (also physical/fax addresses etc.). I can't simply filter on e-mail addresses as I would still like to see all loans (also those without e-mail), with the result whether or not they have an e-mail.

My current query still shows multiple rows for loans who have both mail and another form of address.

```
select l.ApplicationNumber, p1.Name AS Credittaker, a1.EAddress AS 'Mail 
credit taker',
SUM(case 
when c1.ContactChannelTypeID = 2 AND a1.ElectronicAddressTypeID = 1 then 1
else 0 end) as MailID
from Line l 
JOIN Role r1 on (l.ObjID = r1.ObjID_Businessobject)
JOIN Party p1 on (p1.ObjID = r1.ObjID_Party)
JOIN ContactChannel c1 on (p1.ObjID = c1.ObjID_Party)
JOIN Address a1 on (a1.ObjID = c1.ObjID_Address)
WHERE r1.RDNameID = '17' AND r1.Enddate IS NULL AND c1.EndDate IS NULL 
GROUP BY l.ApplicationNumber, p1.Name, a1.EAddress
order by l.ApplicationNumber
```

What I want is for the query to show 1 row per application number, if there is an e-mail (i.e. a row with MailID 1), to show only this value for the application number. If no e-mail is found (i.e. only row with MailID 0), to show this value.

How would I do this?

Example of results vs desired results:

[image: link]

11650 and 11651 only have non e-mail addresses so their value of MailID = 0 is correct. 11652 and 11653 both have an e-mail address and other types of addresses, and should therefore only display MailID = 1. Adding `MAX(MailID)` to the `Group by` clause doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the column name. If I put the case statement in a subquery and refer to it afterwards, I get the error that the an aggregate function can't contain another aggregate function.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select top (1) with ties . . . 
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by l.ApplicationNumber order by MailId desc);
```

I'm not 100% sure you can use a column alias like this in the `order by`.  If not, then :

```
with t as (
      <your query here with no order by>
     )
select 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by applicationNumber order by mailid desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. Adding the row_number to the order clause gives an error for the reason you suspected. However, I get the same error when doing this:
`select t.*
 from (select l.ApplicationNumber, p1.Name, a1.EAddress,
 SUM(case 
 when c1.ContactChannelTypeID = 2 AND a1.ElectronicAddressTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as MailID,
    row_number() over (partition by applicationNumber order by MailiD desc) as seqnum
   *FROM, JOIN AND WHERE CLAUSES*
   GROUP BY l.ApplicationNumber, p1.Name, a1.EAddress 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1`

Have I interpreted your answer wrong?

Comment: @JoostvanAggelen . . . As shown in the answer, you need to define `MailId` using a subquery or CTE and do the `row_number()` in an outer query.